# What is 'tough love'?

Tags: meaning

I saw this in one of the answers in academia community. Just want to know the elaborate meaning of this term. From what Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_love) suggests, this sounds controlling on part of the parents. How do I distinguish tough love from 'controlling'?

Comment: Sorry, but is this question about language or behaviour?

Comment: Both, I guess. I just need an essay on this to clearly get this into my head.

Comment: *Tough* in this sense doesn't mean controlling.  It's a psychobabble word that means refusing to indulge the loved one in self-destructive behavior.

Comment: You've got to be cruel to be kind. That's why I'm voting for this question to be closed.

Comment: You might care to look [here](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think the difference between tough love and controlling is ***why*** it's being done- the motive behind the action.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more suited to a Psychology site than an English Language site.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal - This might be a really thought provoking question to ask (and yes, I *think* it's ok, especially if you're concerned as a parent) on [Parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this question is general reference, since I found fairly definitive information about the term in a general-reference online dictionary (Merriam-Webster.com). But the question seems to have survived previous attempts to close it, so let me reproduce [MW's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tough%20love) here:

> **tough love** *noun* **:** love or affectionate concern expressed in a stern or unsentimental manner (as through discipline) especially to promote responsible behavior
>
> First known use of TOUGH LOVE: 1968

The probable reason that "tough love" caught on as a psychological/sociological/disciplinary term is that it emphasizes that strictness and love are not mutually exclusive notions. Under certain theories of misbehavior, "unconditional love" that expresses itself as "permissive love" or "infinitely forgiving love" is a form of enabling behavior because failing to discipline someone for acts of wrongdoing amounts to insulating misbehavior from any immediate negative consequences that might serve as a deterrent to continued wrongdoing.

But parents (or other authority figures) may worry that dealing severely with infractions will be seen as an indication that the person doing the enforcing doesn't love the person being disciplined. Hence the prominent position of the word *love* in the term *tough love*.

Answer (score 0):

The source is usually a parent, parents, or guardians of some sort. The object is a child or children. Tough love is characterized by oppressive, if not downright abusive, behavior of the parents; frequent dressing-downs; refusal to buy toys and/or clothes; undernourishment (sometimes); and grounding the child for months for the slightest fault, real or imagined. The implication is that the parents (or guardians) do, in fact, love the child (or children), but either have no other way to express it or figure that abuse can be a character builder from which the child or children will greatly benefit in the course of their lives.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a promotion of a person's welfare, especially that of an addict, child, or criminal, by enforcing certain constraints on them, or requiring them to take responsibility for their actions or a political policy designed to encourage self-help by restricting state benefits.
Of course tough love is an expression used when someone treats another person harshly or sternly with the intent to help them in the long run.